# How do I install linux mint on my system which has both SSD and HDD?

Tags: linux, partition, system-installation, hard-disk, ssd

My SSD is of 256gb and my HDD is of 1TB. I want the HDD for larger files and I want Linux mint to be installed in SSD.
I don't want to create a dual boot and I want my system to be a "Linux-only" system. I am confused about the partitions, their types, and their sizes.

---

Are the installation and partitioning same for other distros like POP OS, Zorion, etc.

Comment: What brand/model system/motherboard? UEFI install? Only use gpt partitioning on both drives. Partitioning is unique to each user depending on what you want to use system for. I like multiple installs, so have smaller / (root) partitions and large data partition. But most of my data fits on SSD, so HDD is backup & some additional larger amount of data and more test installs. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/353683/uefi-partitioning-for-dummies &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

Most Linux distributions follow the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/tags/filesystem-hierarchy-standard), with perhaps some deviations. The aforementioned standard defines which directories exists on a Linux system, and the purpose of those directories. You can use this information along with how you intend to use the system, to predict which directories are likely to require the most storage. It is those directories which you would then mount from the HDD.

In a nutshell, I suggest that you study the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard to familiarize yourself with the directories that will be created when you install Linux Mint. Then, during the installation choose to do custom partitioning, which will allow you to create partitions and mount points for all of the directories you want to place on your HDD (examples include /usr /var and /home).

Regarding the partition type, unless you have a reason to choose otherwise you probably won't regret choosing ext4. As for partition sizes... it's really hard to offer any advice. It really depends on your use-case. The most flexible approach would be to use LVM on the HDD so that you can resize the logical volumes (which are similar to partitions) as needed.